# How to properly destruct object within map function using javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, destructuring

I would like to know how can i destruct object within `.map` function using javascript, i have react js component and within `return` method i have the code below:

```
return (
    <>
      {setItems.map(setItem => (
      
      const { childContentfulPartFeatureSetLearnMoreOptionalTextTextNode: learnNode} = setItem
    ....
    </>
```

and i have the next error: `Parsing error: Unexpected token ... = setItem`, i thought what it is

`EsLint`error and used `// eslint-disable-next-line` to disable it, but it didn't work.

UPD full return code:

```
return (
<div className={generalServiceItemClassName} key={guuid()}>
  {setItems.map(setItem => (
   const { childContentfulPartFeatureSetLearnMoreOptionalTextTextNode: learnNode} = setItem

    <div
      key={guuid()}
      className={cx(columnSizeClass, "service-items__item")}
      data-test="service-items"
    >
      {setItem.learnMore ? (
        <LearnMore
          className="service-items__item-learn-more-container"
          learnMoreLink={setItem.learnMore}
          text={}
          textClassName="service-items__item-texts-learn-more"
          learnMoreText={learnNode ? learnNode.setItem : null}
        >
          {renderItem(setItem)}
        </LearnMore>
      ) : (
        renderItem(setItem)
      )}
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

)

Comment: You need to change from `setItems.map(setItem => (` to `setItems.map(setItem => {` if you have statements inside. Also, you need to `return` inside. `()` is used for implicit return.

Comment: Can you show full `return`?

Comment: @NikitaMadeev updated a question with all return method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't have a `const` declaration within an expression, and when you use the concise form of an arrow function (`=>` without a `{` after it), the body is an expression.

You can destructure in the parameter list, though. For instance:

```
{setItems.map(({childContentfulPartFeatureSetLearnMoreOptionalTextTextNode: learnNode}) => (
    // ...use `learnNode` here...
```

In context:

```
return (
    <div className={generalServiceItemClassName} key={guuid()}>
        {setItems.map(({childContentfulPartFeatureSetLearnMoreOptionalTextTextNode: learnNode}) => (
            <div
              key={guuid()}
              className={cx(columnSizeClass, "service-items__item")}
              data-test="service-items"
            >
                {setItem.learnMore ? (
                    <LearnMore
                        className="service-items__item-learn-more-container"
                        learnMoreLink={setItem.learnMore}
                        text={}
                        textClassName="service-items__item-texts-learn-more"
                        learnMoreText={learnNode ? learnNode.setItem : null}
                    >
                        {renderItem(setItem)}
                    </LearnMore>
                    ) : (
                        renderItem(setItem)
                    )
                }
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this. (destructure and renaming)

```
const setItems = [{ abc: 5 }];
return (
  <>
    {setItems.map((setItem) => {
      const { abc: xyz } = setItem;
      return <div>{xyz}</div>;
    })}
  </>
);
```

// Alternate way, simplified.

```
return (
  <>
    {setItems.map(({ abc: xyz }) => (
      <div>{xyz}</div>
    ))}
  </>
);
```